# In Excel, how do you find the average of cells based on the criteria of other cells?

Tags: excel, indexing, max, average, criteria

The Excel sheet has rows of numbers. For each of those rows, I need to find the average of the the cell that contains the maximum  and whatever cell is to the left of that maximum.

For example...

[image: Example sheet]

- For row 1, I would need to get average of D1 (the maximum) and C1 (the value to the left of the maximum).
- For row 2, I would need to get the average of E2 (the maximum) and D2 (the value to the left of the maximum).
- For row 3, I would need to get the average of D3 (the maximum) and C3 (the value to the left of the maximum).

What equations and functions will return those averaged values?

Comment: INDEX/MATCH, MAX, and AVERAGE.

Comment: What if the maximum occurs at the far left of a row?

Answer (score 2):

Try following formula:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A1:G1,,N(IF(1,MATCH(MAX(A1:G1),A1:G1,0)-{1,0}))))
```

If the max value will be in the first column, then you will get error.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You're the best. It works perfectly.